# Does anyone have a handle on the new weapons in Worms Reloaded?

Tags: worms-reloaded

So new Worms is coming out (not in 3D (huzzah)). Anyone got a handle on the new weapons? According to Steam, new weapons include Super Bunker Buster, Ferrets, Poison Strike, Worship, Sentry Gun, Electromagnet, Buffalo of Lies...

Any more that anyone knows of? Or details on these weapons?

Comment: Anything about a unreleased game is subject to change over time.

Comment: @Macha The game is due out in less than a month, there's not much going to change at this stage in the game. We're not talking about an alpha / beta candidate here. While there may be minor tweaks, the relevant information is going to be mostly if not entirely accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Worms Reloaded new weapons detailed](http://www.incgamers.com/News/24378/worms-reloaded-new-weapons-detailed)

[Game trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wtf419b1iMI)

Comment: The first link is now 404. This is why we frown on link-only answers :-(